# Web service with .net does not connect to mysql db in interner information service

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, web-services, iis

I've written a webservice that connects to a mysql database and provides api. It works fine when I run it in visual studio. Now I want it to work when I put it in internet information service. But api does not return. My single page appication that expects this api to run gives me the error below

```
 GET http://localhost:8024/api/Interviewee 500 (Internal Server Error)


angular.js:15536 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at IntervieweeService.Controllers.IntervieweeController.GetInterviewees() in C:\\Projects\\IntervieweeApp\\IntervieweeService\\IntervieweeService\\Controllers\\IntervieweeController.cs:line 30\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"},"status":500,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:8024/api/Interviewee","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error","xhrStatus":"complete"}
(anonymous) @ angular.js:15536
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11815
processChecks @ angular.js:17946
$digest @ angular.js:19075
$apply @ angular.js:19463
done @ angular.js:13312
completeRequest @ angular.js:13569
requestLoaded @ angular.js:13474
load (async)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13457
sendReq @ angular.js:13257
serverRequest @ angular.js:12998
processQueue @ angular.js:17914
(anonymous) @ angular.js:17962
$digest @ angular.js:19075
$apply @ angular.js:19463
done @ angular.js:13312
completeRequest @ angular.js:13569
requestLoaded @ angular.js:13474
load (async)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13457
sendReq @ angular.js:13257
serverRequest @ angular.js:12998
processQueue @ angular.js:17914
(anonymous) @ angular.js:17962
$digest @ angular.js:19075
$apply @ angular.js:19463
bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1945
invoke @ angular.js:5122
doBootstrap @ angular.js:1943
bootstrap @ angular.js:1963
angularInit @ angular.js:1848
(anonymous) @ angular.js:36216
fire @ jquery-2.2.4.js:3187
fireWith @ jquery-2.2.4.js:3317
ready @ jquery-2.2.4.js:3536
completed @ jquery-2.2.4.js:3552
```

connection string

```
Server=localhost;Port=8024;Database=intervieweedb;Uid=rrrr;Pwd=111;
```

How can I make this work? Thanks

Comment: Have you debugged it already? a 500 is very generic can you provide the actual error?

Comment: How does your connection string looks like? Dont you get any details in the body of the response? You should see the stack trace of the exception thrown.

Comment: I added the full error and the connection string

Comment: According to the documentation of the .net connector, there are quite a lot of fine-tune parameters available in the connection string. Are you sure you are properly  disposing all unused connections in your code? IIS is managing application pools, that means you might awaken many instances that could easily consume the connection pool.

Comment: @ZorgoZ all connections are created in using blocks. I had no problem when I run the program with visual studio

Comment: VS or IIS dev runs a single instance only. You should try disabling connection pooling in the connection string. If that helps, you should fine-tune the pool size in relation to the IIS instance settings. But thst's only an idea, I don't use mysql with iis, but years ago mssql connector had similar problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267513/how-to-monitor-connection-pooling-for-net-mysql-data-connector-in-iis

Comment: The port in your connection string is wrong. If you're accessing your website at `http://localhost:8024/api/Interviewee` then port 8024 is being used by your web server. `"Server=localhost;Port=8024"` in your connection string must be wrong because MySQL needs to be running on a different port.

Comment: Now It works thank you!

Comment: @Thunfische Great, I'll add it as an answer; please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're accessing your website at http://localhost:8024/api/Interviewee then port 8024 is being used by your web server. `Server=localhost;Port=8024` in your connection string is wrong because MySQL needs to be running on a different port.

Change the `Port` in your MySQL connection string to the port number of your MySQL server (usually `3306`).